# Scaffold-DbContext doesn’t appear to work with EF Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Try to run this command in Package Manager Console:

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models/Business/ToolsNawDbEntities

Getting this error:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.0
      1.0.0-rc2-3002702
      1.0.1
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.0'.
Process finished with non-zero exit code
```

I checked my project.json and it is there:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }
```

Just to make sure I expanded and checked my References and it is present.

It is looking in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` where there is no 1.1.0 version. Only these 3 below are installed:

- 1.0.0-rc2-3002702
- 1.0.0
- 1.0.1

However in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.App` there are 4 versions installed:

- 1.0.0-rc2-3002702
- 1.0.0
- 1.0.1
- 1.1.0

So it is present over there. How do I make this work? I have no idea what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try installing the .NET Core 1.1 runtime from here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core (both x64 and x86)?

Comment: I already thought I was missing something big, that fixed my problem, tnkx!

Comment: You must select 'Current' tab to see 1.1 version - otherwise you currently only see 1.01